# Show all variations of 2 characters in postgres

Tags: postgresql

How would I do this in postgres :

Lets say I have an x and a y and I want to show all possible combinations :

```
xx
yy
xy
yx
```

How can I make postgres do this for me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with characters (c) as (
  select unnest(string_to_array('xy', null))
) 
select *
from characters c1
  cross join characters c2
```

**Edit:**

Apparently this does not work in 8.4, but the following should:

```
with characters (c) as (
  select unnest(regexp_split_to_array('xy', ''))
) 
select *
from characters c1
  cross join characters c2
```

Thanks to Bruno for testing this.

Comment: that gives me no output I'm affraid :/

Comment: No output? Works fine over here, PostgreSQL version 9.1 used to test.

Comment: I'm still running 8.4 :(

Comment: @LucasKauffman: That should work on 8.4 as well (it has CTEs, unnest and string_to_array)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with 8.4 either, but replacing `string_to_array('xy', null)` with `regexp_split_to_array('xy', '')` works. Credit to [this thread](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2009-07/msg01640.php), which may have something to do with support for `NULL` as a delimiter in more recent versions.

Comment: Aha! `CROSS JOIN` *does* have a valid use.