# PostgreSQL: reuse of complex intermediate result in same query

Tags: performance, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL (8.4), I'm creating a view that summarizes various results from a few tables (e.g creating columns `a`, `b`, `c` in the view), and then I need to combine some of these results together in the same query (e.g. `a+b`, `a-b`, `(a+b)/c`, ...), so as to produce the final results. What I'm noticing is that the intermediate results are fully computed each time they are used, even if it's done within the same query.

Is there a way to optimize this so as to avoid those same results to be computed every time?

Here is a simplified example that reproduces the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    log_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    test1_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES test1(id),
    category VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    col1 INTEGER,
    col2 INTEGER
);
CREATE INDEX test_category_idx ON test2(category);

-- Added after edit to this question
CREATE INDEX test_id_idx ON test2(test1_id);

-- Populating with test data.
INSERT INTO test1(log_timestamp)
    SELECT * FROM generate_series('2011-01-01'::timestamp, '2012-01-01'::timestamp, '1 hour');
INSERT INTO test2
    SELECT id, substr(upper(md5(random()::TEXT)), 1, 1),
               (20000*random()-10000)::int, (3000*random()-200)::int FROM test1;
INSERT INTO test2
    SELECT id, substr(upper(md5(random()::TEXT)), 1, 1),
               (2000*random()-1000)::int, (3000*random()-200)::int FROM test1;
INSERT INTO test2
    SELECT id, substr(upper(md5(random()::TEXT)), 1, 1),
               (2000*random()-40)::int, (3000*random()-200)::int FROM test1;
```

Here is a view that performs the most time-consuming operations:

```
CREATE VIEW testview1 AS
    SELECT
       t1.id,
       t1.log_timestamp,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.col1) FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.test1_id=t1.id AND category='A') AS a,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.col2) FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.test1_id=t1.id AND category='B') AS b,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.col1 - t2.col2) FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.test1_id=t1.id AND category='C') AS c
    FROM test1 t1;
```

- `SELECT a FROM testview1` produces [this plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/KxF) (via `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`):

  ```
   Seq Scan on test1 t1  (cost=0.00..1787086.55 rows=8761 width=4) (actual time=12.877..10517.575 rows=8761 loops=1)
     SubPlan 1
       ->  Aggregate  (cost=203.96..203.97 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.193..1.193 rows=1 loops=8761)
             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=36.49..203.95 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.109..1.177 rows=0 loops=8761)
                   Recheck Cond: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
                   Filter: (test1_id = $0)
                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_category_idx  (cost=0.00..36.49 rows=1631 width=0) (actual time=0.414..0.414 rows=1631 loops=8761)
                         Index Cond: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
   Total runtime: 10522.346 ms
  ```

- `SELECT a, a FROM testview1` produces [this plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/kD0):

  ```
   Seq Scan on test1 t1  (cost=0.00..3574037.50 rows=8761 width=4) (actual time=3.343..20550.817 rows=8761 loops=1)
     SubPlan 1
       ->  Aggregate  (cost=203.96..203.97 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.183..1.183 rows=1 loops=8761)
             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=36.49..203.95 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.100..1.166 rows=0 loops=8761)
                   Recheck Cond: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
                   Filter: (test1_id = $0)
                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_category_idx  (cost=0.00..36.49 rows=1631 width=0) (actual time=0.418..0.418 rows=1631 loops=8761)
                         Index Cond: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
     SubPlan 2
       ->  Aggregate  (cost=203.96..203.97 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.154..1.154 rows=1 loops=8761)
             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=36.49..203.95 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.083..1.143 rows=0 loops=8761)
                   Recheck Cond: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
                   Filter: (test1_id = $0)
                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_category_idx  (cost=0.00..36.49 rows=1631 width=0) (actual time=0.426..0.426 rows=1631 loops=8761)
                         Index Cond: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
   Total runtime: 20557.581 ms
  ```

Here, selecting `a, a` takes twice as long as selecting `a`, whereas they could really be computed just once. For example, with `SELECT a, a+b, a-b FROM testview1`, it goes through the sub-plan for `a` 3 times and through `b` twice, whereas the execution time could be reduced to 2/5 of the total time (assuming + and - are negligible here).

It's a good thing it doesn't compute the unused columns (`b` and `c`) when they're not needed, but is there a way to make it compute the same used columns from the view only once?

**EDIT:**
@Frank Heikens correctly suggested to use an index, which was missing in the example above. While it does improve the speed for each sub-plan, it doesn't prevent the same sub-query to be computed multiple times. Sorry, I should have put this in the initial question to make it clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Apologies for answering my own question, but after reading [this unrelated question and answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9036/2129), it occurred to me I should try using a CTE instead. It works.)

Here is another view, similar to `testview1` in the question, but that uses a [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html):

```
CREATE VIEW testview2 AS
    WITH testcte AS (SELECT
       t1.id,
       t1.log_timestamp,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.col1) FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.test1_id=t1.id AND category='A') AS a,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.col2) FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.test1_id=t1.id AND category='B') AS b,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.col1 - t2.col2) FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.test1_id=t1.id AND category='C') AS c
      FROM test1 t1)
    SELECT * FROM testcte;
```

(This is just an example, I'm not suggesting that combining a view and a CTE are a necessarily a good idea: a CTE might be enough.)

Unlike `testview1`, the query plan for `SELECT a FROM testview2` now also computes `b` and `c`, which were ignored since unused in `testview1`:

```
Subquery Scan testview2  (cost=395272.42..395535.25 rows=8761 width=8) (actual time=0.256..607.941 rows=8761 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on testcte  (cost=395272.42..395447.64 rows=8761 width=36) (actual time=0.255..604.106 rows=8761 loops=1)
         CTE testcte
           ->  Seq Scan on test1 t1  (cost=0.00..395272.42 rows=8761 width=12) (actual time=0.252..589.358 rows=8761 loops=1)
                 SubPlan 1
                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=15.02..15.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=8761)
                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=4.28..15.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=8761)
                               Recheck Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                               Filter: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_if_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=3 loops=8761)
                                     Index Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                 SubPlan 2
                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=15.02..15.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=8761)
                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=4.28..15.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=8761)
                               Recheck Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                               Filter: ((category)::text = 'B'::text)
                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_if_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=3 loops=8761)
                                     Index Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                 SubPlan 3
                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=15.02..15.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=8761)
                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=4.28..15.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=0 loops=8761)
                               Recheck Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                               Filter: ((category)::text = 'C'::text)
                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_if_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=3 loops=8761)
                                     Index Cond: (test1_id = $0)
```

However, it doesn't re-compute the results that are used multiple times within the same query (which was the objective).

Unlike `testview1` with which `SELECT a, a, a, a, a` took 5 times longer than `SELECT a`, here `SELECT a, a, a, a, a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c FROM testview2` takes just as long as `SELECT a FROM testview2` or `SELECT a, b, c FROM testview2`. It only goes through `a`, `b` and `c` once:

```
 Subquery Scan testview2  (cost=395272.42..395600.96 rows=8761 width=24) (actual time=0.147..562.790 rows=8761 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on testcte  (cost=395272.42..395447.64 rows=8761 width=36) (actual time=0.144..554.194 rows=8761 loops=1)
         CTE testcte
           ->  Seq Scan on test1 t1  (cost=0.00..395272.42 rows=8761 width=12) (actual time=0.140..542.657 rows=8761 loops=1)
                 SubPlan 1
                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=15.02..15.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=8761)
                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=4.28..15.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=0 loops=8761)
                               Recheck Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                               Filter: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_if_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=3 loops=8761)
                                     Index Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                 SubPlan 2
                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=15.02..15.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=8761)
                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=4.28..15.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=8761)
                               Recheck Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                               Filter: ((category)::text = 'B'::text)
                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_if_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=3 loops=8761)
                                     Index Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                 SubPlan 3
                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=15.02..15.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=8761)
                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=4.28..15.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=8761)
                               Recheck Cond: (test1_id = $0)
                               Filter: ((category)::text = 'C'::text)
                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_if_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=3 loops=8761)
                                     Index Cond: (test1_id = $0)
```

Comment: No need to apologise! :-) In fact there is a badge *Self Learner* for answering your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

You need an index on test1_id in table test2, that will change things.

```
Seq Scan on test1 t1  (cost=0.00..301450.63 rows=8761 width=12) (actual time=0.108..229.859 rows=8761 loops=1)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=11.45..11.46 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=8761)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=3.27..11.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=8761)
                Recheck Cond: (test1_id = t1.id)
                Filter: ((category)::text = 'A'::text)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_id  (cost=0.00..3.27 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=3 loops=8761)
                      Index Cond: (test1_id = t1.id)
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=11.45..11.46 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=8761)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=3.27..11.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=8761)
                Recheck Cond: (test1_id = t1.id)
                Filter: ((category)::text = 'B'::text)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_id  (cost=0.00..3.27 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=3 loops=8761)
                      Index Cond: (test1_id = t1.id)
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=11.46..11.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=8761)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2 t2  (cost=3.27..11.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=8761)
                Recheck Cond: (test1_id = t1.id)
                Filter: ((category)::text = 'C'::text)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_id  (cost=0.00..3.27 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=3 loops=8761)
                      Index Cond: (test1_id = t1.id)
Total runtime: 232.419 ms
```

Comment: Thank you, this does improve the performance indeed, but my actual table already has that corresponding index in fact. The initial problem is still present: `SELECT a, a, a, a, a FROM testview1` still takes 5 times longer than `SELECT a FROM testview1`.